# Tomcat 8 speed gets degraded over time

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, file-upload, tomcat8

I am using **Tomcat 8.5** to host a WAR which is used for java REST services.

In my rest service, I create a connection and take a multi-part form data file from user, scan it using a scan engine and return the result. At the start, tomcat is running fine and giving a speed of almost 57-58 Mbps but degrades over time (degrades to nearly half in 5-8 min)

My `setenv.bat` file looks like this.

```
"set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m -Xmx5120m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xincgc -server""
```

`JVM` is using `ParNewGC` for garbage collection.

my `server.xml` file looks like this

```
<Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="100" minSpareThreads="8" maxSpareThreads="10" acceptorThreadCount="16" acceptCount="500"/>



    <!--acceptCount :The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused. The default value is 100. 



    A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" socket.rxBufSize="10000000" socket.txBufSize="3000000" socket.directBuffer="true" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
```

As my response is completely dynamic. I am **not using any type of caching**. please help me with this issue.

Comment: the only way to have an idea of what's going on is to use a profiler and track memory consumption as well as thread activity.

Comment: thankyou for your suggestion , can you please tell me how can i do that , i am monitoring CPU consumption and see CPU starvation as performance starts to degrade .

Comment: eg. use JProfiler and connect to your live JVM. Then, you get several tabs/views. One is CPU activity, another is Threads activity. This helps greatly to understand what happens, who uses the resources and the eventual locks creating starvation between threads.

Comment: i did it sir. whats happening is that most of my threads are controlled by I/o which reduces the run able threads which in turn leads to performance degradation. can you suggest any solution to this??

Comment: not sure what you mean. how many threads are active? what are the resources the share? how are the locks managed? does the number of active threads grow with time? do you free every resources (streams, connections, etc...)

Comment: over the time i/o threads increases, waiting threads also increases and runable threads (threads which does the actual work decreases from 6-7 to 0 ) over time. i haven't done anything to manage locks as it is threads of tomcat also , GC is running to free up the resources

Comment: @spi i also checked that if it is a network issue or not and found that its not a network problem it is problem from server side only if it is clearing issue after restarting the server after every 5 GB what can be the issue according to you??.

Comment: its really hard to tell without the code or the results of the profiling. If you are on jdk8, the flag -Xincgc is now deprecated but I doubt it can cause your issue. I would try to comment/simplify the code until the problem goes away. A non-closed stream somewhere in the code could cause these kind of symptoms. Dropping random jars in $TOMCAT/lib could also. Bad/outdated version of the Apache's file upload api could too... But I can't tell for sure

Comment: ok! i will try that out (commenting the code) and get back to you . your support is helping me a lot. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a error due to a large number of **open tcp/ip connections** .Try connecting with server for once and send data check for sockets when you see a performance degradation.

In windows, you can use `netstat-an` to check the open sockets.